# How to avoid the "for" loop in python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

Suppose X is an ndarray with shape (3,8,8), and y is another array with shape (3,). I want to multiply each (8,8) slice of X to one element of y, and then add the resultant. Using a for loop, this can be done as follows:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(3,8,8)
y = np.random.rand(3)
temp = 0
for k in range(3):
    temp = temp+y[k]*X[k,:,:]
```

Is there any way to avoid the "for" loop for this? Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: `While True` iteration with an escape condition instead?

Comment: @Skully I actually want a vectorized version with any loop.

Comment: @KellyBundy Please consider X and y to be random.

Comment: @KellyBundy I have edited the code. Does this make sense now?

Comment: `(y[:,None,None]*X).sum(0)` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Have you spent enough time reading numpy basics to encounter `broadcasting`?

```
(y[:,None,None]*X).sum(axis=0)
```

should work.

### edit

`X` is (3,8,8).

`y` needs to be (3,1,1) to broadcast with it.

Understanding `broadcasting` is essential when trying to replace loops.

Comment: `broadcasting` is about half way down the `beginner's` page, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#broadcasting

Comment: Maybe! But I am not interested. It is a crime? Should I leave the planet? Please, I am scared!

Comment: don't worry Nash! I have years in python and still learning broadcasting tricks

Comment: yeah broadcasting is a pretty advanced feature in numpy… even if you see it in a tutorial you wont understand how to implement specific cases. and no, not everybody is learning from the official docs from beginning to end nowdays